# navigator.userAgent not working

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I'm trying to check with the User Agent Switcher if a device is mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
alert(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried with `navigator.userAgent.match`.
Why does the alert always print false?

Comment: Please don't use `userAgent` sniffing. The best practice is to use feature detection and not browser detection. But for the purposes of this question, have you checked what the value of `userAgent` actually is?

Comment: One way of doing things right: [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: `alert(navigator.userAgent)` always prints the same string `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows  NT6.1; Win64; x6 [...]`

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work with user-agent switcher but it does on the device.

Comment: @JLRishe can you please explain more about 'feature detection' you are talking about. Can  you please give me an example in Javascript. I am having problem that userAgent is not correct with my real browser version. For example, My Chrome is 114.0.5735.134, but the navigator.userAgent show it is 114.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It prints false if it's false, execute a verbose and explicit test:

```
alert(
    'Your user-agent:\n' +
    navigator.userAgent + '\n' +
    (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ?
        'match with Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini':
        'does not match with Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini'
    )
);
```

Comment: This actually doesn't print anything

Comment: Ok, you missed the concatenation symbol. Anyway it always prints `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT6.1; Win64; x6 [...]`

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT6.1; Win64; x6` is your own user-agent, and  what is important is the end of the alert : match vs. does not match. In your case, you're not on a mobile device, so you does not match, it's exactly what this code is supposed to do.